# vertical-align:middle does not align content in the middle when used with bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three column's and the middle column has a button which i want to vertially align in the middle.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="mypanel">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="mypanel">
            <div style="vertical-align:middle">
                <button type="button">Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="mypanel">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Style**

```
  .mypanel {
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

However `vertical-align:middle` does not make any affect on the content of the `div`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j8m3z798/2/)**

Comment: Demo not working.

Comment: sorry Wrong link. should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.mypanel {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table;
}

 .mypanel div{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

this will solve the problem 
https://jsfiddle.net/xyx3enz1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .mypanel {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .text-centered {
                text-align: center;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
     }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="mypanel">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="mypanel">
            <div class="text-centered">
                <button type="button">Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="mypanel">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite approach is to use pseudo elements like :after to create an element, set its height, and then vertical align based on that. It doesn't require much CSS either:

```
// I changed the col-md-1 to col-md-4 for this example
.col-md-4 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.col-md-4 .mypanel {
   height: 100%; // Make sure .mypanel is set to 100% height otherwise our pseudo element won't know what 100% height is
}

// Here is the pseudo element, set the vertical align here and on your button
.col-md-4:nth-child(2) .mypanel:after {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.col-md-4:nth-child(2) .mypanel button {
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Check out this working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rk9pazq/).